# Javascript: Empty html div contents after Window.print()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

On button click, I'm using `window.print()` of javascript for printing `print_div` contents,

But because of some security issue, i wanted to avoid the multiple printing (like using Cntrl + P) options, So i was thinking of to clear `print_div` contents, that users can't re-print again and again.

Rough Code here,

```
document.getElementById("print_div").innerHTML = //Some contents to be printed on paper.
window.print()
document.getElementById("print_div").innerHTML = '' // Clearing old contents to avoid mis-use
```

But this code not working at all, its clearing `print_div` contents before creating print preview like in chrome.(i guessed, working Asynchronously)

Could any one tell me, where am doing wrong here?

**Note**: Am using `Chrome: 22.0.1229.92 m` to test my code & i want to go for chrome only.

Comment: If I open devtools on this very page and type: `document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "Test"; window.print(); document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = '';` everything will work as expected. I'll get the preview with "Test" and when I close the print dialog `#content` div will be empty. `window.print()` doesn't seem to be asynchronous .

Comment: Yeh..its working fine at devtools but not in actual code. BTW am trying to clear this by using setTimeOut
Its weird but working for me.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing in the print_div and in next step you are clearing the same. Therefore it shows empty. You can store printing data in a variable. Then display it in the print_div and you can clear the variable.

```
var print = "";
print += "<p>Something </p><br/>";
print += "<table><tr><td>Something</td><td>Something</td></tr> 
                <tr><td>Something</td><td>Something</td></tr> </table>";
document.getElementById("print_div").innerHTML = print;
print = "";
```

something like this. Set this javascript to button onsubmit event.

Comment: I don't think that your solution makes much sense. After `print` variable is cleared `document.getElementById("print_div")` will still contain data that still can be printed. We want to prevent user for printing multiple times here.

Answer (score 3):

It's because print window wasn't loaded.

```
var showPrintWindow = function (context) {
        var printWindow = window.open('', '');
        var doc = printWindow.document;
        doc.write("<html><head>");
        doc.write("<link href='/css/printReport.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='print' />");
        doc.write("</head><body>");
        doc.write(context);
        doc.write("</body></html>");
        doc.close();

        function show() {
          if (doc.readyState === "complete") {
              printWindow.focus();
              printWindow.print();
              printWindow.close();
          } else {
              setTimeout(show, 100);
          }
        };
        show();
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use setTimeout method and try it.

```
setTimeout("your code or function etc",mili seconds)

setTimeout("document.getElementById('print_div').innerHTML = ''",5000);
```

Comment: Yup...that's what i did now..Thanks a ton... :)

Comment: SetTimeout function wait 5 seconds then after its clear print div.In your code print div is clear does not wait for print.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem to yours in Chrome, it was showing blank page in Print Preview. Tried using setTimeout but it didn't work. What worked was window.onload.

```
<div id="printableArea">
      <h1>Print me</h1>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="print a div!" />
```

javascript:

```
    function printDiv(divName) {

        var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
        w = window.open();

        w.document.write(printContents);
        w.document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript">' + 'window.onload = function() { window.print(); window.close(); };' + '</sc' + 'ript>');

        w.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        w.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you split the tags like ('<scr' + 'ipt) and ('</sc' + 'ript>')?

Answer (score 0):

I would not go for the setTimeout, it will only work if the user immediately comfirms the print, which you cannot assume blindly..

I would do something like the following:

```
var html = "<html><head></head><body>" + $("print_div").html() + "</body></html>";
var newWindow= window.open("", "PrintWindow",  
"width=100,height=50,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes");  
newWindow.document.writeln(html);  
newWindow.document.close();  
newWindow.focus();  
newWindow.print();  
newWindow.close();
```

and then perform your wipe

```
$('print_div').clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function(){printWindow.document.close();
 printWindow.print();}, 500);
```

it will work

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.